# How to calculate values from multiple schemas in elixir/phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, calculated-field

Good Afternoon,

Im relatively new to Elixir and Phoenix; however, i'm looking for a way to calculate or perform any maths on a set of values produced from more than one schema.

i.e You input some percentages for different products on a page, and then when submitted you can show the total percentage entered from all the products.

I've got all individual percentages showing on the show.html page, but not sure how to do the arithmetic section for it.

Thank you

Comment: Some additional information about the operations you're trying to do on the input would be helpful.

There's the erlang math module http://erlang.org/doc/man/math.html that you can call directly from elixir by doing things `:math.pow(2, 2)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply;

So for example the user enters a few percentages of an item in a field (Schema 1 -Concentrations) and I was wondering how to actually tally all those fields and display them in the show.html for the recipe

Comment: For those in the same situation, I've solved it using java script, used the correct class and id's and then did the maths through app.js. After that the fields were automatically set when the form submits.